# PHP Uploading images and getting the url

Tags: php, html

I've been working on a premade image upload template for fun and I'm not too good with php so I can't seem to get around this problem.

I need to be able to extract the direct link to my image (the `$upload_dir` variable + file extension) so I can use it in my `index.php` page. I've tried to include my `post_file.php` file in my `index.php` but I am getting the `Wrong HTTP-method` message.

My website is in `html5` and it's using the drag-and-drop to initiate the uploading if that is something that messes with my upload file.

**post_file.php**:

```
$demo_mode = false;
$upload_dir = 'uploads/'.date(d).rand(0000,9999);
$allowed_ext = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');

if (strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != 'post') {
    exit_status('Error! Wrong HTTP method!');
}

if (array_key_exists('pic',$_FILES) && $_FILES['pic']['error'] == 0 ) {
    $pic = $_FILES['pic'];

    if (!in_array(get_extension($pic['name']),$allowed_ext)) {
        exit_status('Only '.implode(',',$allowed_ext).' files are allowed!');
    }    

    // Uploads are being ignored, but logged.
    if ($demo_mode) {
        $line = implode('        ', array( date('r'), $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $pic['size'], $pic['name']));
        file_put_contents('log.txt', $line.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

        exit_status('Uploads are ignored in demo mode.');
    }

    // Move image,rename it and log it all
    if (move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.'.'.get_extension($pic['name']))) {         
        $line = implode('        ', array( date(r),    'http://website.com/'.$upload_dir.'.'.get_extension($pic['name'])));
        file_put_contents('log.txt', $line.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

        exit_status('Upload was successful');
    }
}

exit_status('Something went wrong with your upload!');
```

**Functions**

```
function exit_status($str) {
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>$str));
    exit;
}

function get_extension($file_name) {
    $ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $ext = array_pop($ext);
    return strtolower($ext);
}
```

When I use the `include('post_file.php')` is when I receive the error message, how can I get the new image name + path and extension without including the `post_file.php` in my `index.php` file and then echo it in a variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Use your `post_file.php` to perform the upload task, then send the browser to the file using a header redirect, or return it to `http://example.com/index.php?last_file_uploaded=example.com/path/to/uploaded_file.ext` and use PHP to detect and display that on the page. There's a number of ways to do this, though. The two scripts you're showing do not seem to be compatible in the way you're suggesting, in the manner they are written (as you've found out).

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer! As I said I'm not very good with php, could you suggest a way to do this? I just tried to do the `header("Location: http://example.com/".$upload_dir.'.'.get_extension($pic['name']));` but it did not work at all. I probably implemented it wrong, I pasted it right after the `exit_status(Upload was successful);`.

Comment: Your `exit_status()` function stops processing. You would need to call `header()` before *any* `exit` or `die` is called. Probably, I would make a wrapper `exit_success($path_to_file);` that calls your `exit_status()` *within* that function.

Comment: I understand the `exit_status()` functionality now, thanks! Is there a way to rewrite the `exit_status()` to include `header()` if the file was uploaded successfully? I was thinking via an if-statement...? (since I understand those pretty well) Thank you again for helping me Jared!